# android help in designing game board

Tags: android

I am developing a memory matching game and I have a little problem in designing the game board.

My game board layout consists of a linear layout containing a table layout.

In the game activity I generate the table rows dynamically based on the game level.

Each table row contains number of image views.

When displaying the game, the table contents are aligned to the left.

I configured both the linear layout, the table layout, and each of the table rows to be centered using the gravity property but I still see the contents aligned to left.

What should I do to make the contents centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [Hello Views tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html)? I think it may answer some of your questions.